# Android Studio error install Java

Tags: android

I am trying to install the Android Studio and there is an error that I can not fix. See attached picture:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are getting Gradle errors. Please find out how to copy the text of those errors to the clipboard, then paste them here, in a formatted block, minus the txtspk and the plz-halp-me begging.

Comment: 1.Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: 2.Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Lovely. Please edit them into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Aapt2` is enabled by default when you use `android plugin` for `gradle 3.0`.

This is to improve incremental resource processing

can you try this?

Open the `gradle.properties` and add this:

`android.enableAapt2=false`